# Updating NotesDocument does not update bound NotesXspDocument

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to understand the relationship between a data source on an XPage and its corresponding NotesDocument.

I have two data sources `doc1` and `doc2` bound to an XPage with various fields bound to either the first or second doc.  `doc1` is filled by the user but I use a text box with typeahead to search for a doc to bind to `doc2`. When the user clicks one of the results from the typeahead, I try to attach the found doc to `doc2` but it doesn't work. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="doc1" formName="form1"
            documentId="#{sessionScope.clientUNID}" databaseName="${sessionScope.ClientsDbPath}"
            action="#{viewScope.DocEditMode}" ignoreRequestParams="true" />
        <xp:dominoDocument var="doc2" formName="form2"
            documentId="#{viewScope.providerUNID}" databaseName="${sessionScope.ProvidersDbPath}"
            action="#{viewScope.DocEditMode}" ignoreRequestParams="true" />
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:inputText id="providerFullName" value="#{doc1.providerFullName}">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Last name..." />
        </xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:typeAhead mode="partial" minChars="1" ignoreCase="true"
            valueList="#{javascript:@DbColumn(sessionScope.ProvidersDbPath, 'providerLookup', 1)}" />
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panel1"
            disableValidators="true">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var pDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(sessionScope.ServerName, sessionScope.ProvidersDbPath);
var pView:NotesView = pDB.getView('providerLookup');
var result = getComponent('providerFullName').getValue();
var tmpDoc:NotesDocument = pView.getDocumentByKey(result, true); 
if (tmpDoc != null) {

    //here I am trying to associate the found doc with the data source
    var prDoc:NotesDocument = doc2.getDocument();
    prDoc = tmpDoc;

    //the back-end assignment works because this DOES return the last name
    print('prDoc lastname: ' + prDoc.getItemValueString('lastName'));

    //then I try to update the Xsp doc from the changed back-end doc but it returns nothing
    doc2.getDocument(true);
    print('doc2 lastname: ' + doc2.getItemValueString('lastName'));

}}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

Is the data source relationship only one-way? That is, can I only push data from the XspDocument to the NotesDocument (via an input text field) but cannot push data back up from the NotesDocument to the XspDocument if the NotesDocument was programmatically updated?

Also, I'm not sure if I need the `action` parameter on `doc2`. I think that parameter is only needed if it were the sole data source on the page...?

Comment: Just going futher down the workflow path, ultimately, which document is saved? doc1 or doc2 or both?

Comment: @PaulDella-Nebbia - Eventually both are saved as separate docs. I do copy a few redundant fields from doc2 to doc1 but overall they contain different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (tmpDoc != null) {
    //here I am trying to associate the found doc with the data source
    var prDoc:NotesDocument = doc2.getDocument();
```

Here you throw away the result of doc2.getDocument...

```
    prDoc = tmpDoc;

    //the back-end assignment works because this DOES return the last name
    print('prDoc lastname: ' + prDoc.getItemValueString('lastName'));

    //then I try to update the Xsp doc from the changed back-end doc but it returns nothing
    doc2.getDocument(true);
```

Does viewScope.providerUNID contain a valid noteID? If not, doc2 is a temporary DominoDocument, which has no back-end Document.

```
    print('doc2 lastname: ' + doc2.getItemValueString('lastName'));
```

So nothing can be retrieved from it.

Datasource is first, Document follows.

If you want to attach the found doc to doc2, you have to set viewScope.providerUNID to its noteID and partially refresh that part of your code that references doc2. For instance, you could create a new xp:panel and move the definition of doc2 there, so that when you refresh the panel, the datasource will be loaded.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Rather than binding `doc2` to the page, I added an `xp:panel`, moved `doc2` and the `xp:inputText` field into it. In the `onChange` event I updated `viewScope.providerUNID` from `doc2` and refreshed the panel and everything worked perfectly.